# Javascript if statement with strict equality operator question

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to analyze this solution for the leetcode problem "392. Is Subsequence" as proposed by Mr. raunak1508. I was confused behind the meaning of the first *if statement*. `if(j===t.length)`. I believe that part of the code determines when to return false or to proceed to the next if statement `if(s[i]===t[j])`.

Can someone advise if what I'm thinking is correct?

I think the context behind `if(j===t.length)` means that if the `var j` contains all specific values of `var t` which is "ahbgdc" it then returns false....

...But if the second *if statement* `if(s[i]===t[j])` gets completed first by producing a match it returns true. In this case the first if statement `if(j===t.length)`does not even have a chance to return false.

```js
//"abz" will return false

let s="abz"
let t="ahbgdc"

function isSubsequence(s, t) {
    let i=0;                               
    let j=0;                             
 while(i<s.length){        
        if(j===t.length){ 
        console.log("t.length is  " + t.length)
            return false;
        }
        if(s[i]===t[j]){                 
            i++;
        }
        j++;
        console.log("j is  "+ j);
     
    }
return true;                              

}
console.log(isSubsequence(s, t));
```

```js
let s="abc"
let t="ahbgdc"

function isSubsequence(s, t) {
    let i=0;                                
    let j=0;                               
 while(i<s.length){             
        if(j===t.length){ 
       
            return false;
        }
        if(s[i]===t[j]){                   
            i++;
        }
        j++;
        console.log("j is  "+ j);
        console.log("t.length is  " + t.length)

    }
return true;                               

}
console.log(isSubsequence(s, t));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `j` is just the currentIndex of `t`, since we are moving ahead in `t`, while `i` do the same for `s`

```
  let s="abz"
   let t="ahbgdc"
```

initially `i  = 0` and `j = 0` means they both are point to fist character index of s and t respectfully.

the condition for true is reaching `i === 2` by `i < s.length`  before reaching `j === 7` by `j === t.length`.

This simply means that we should reach final character of `s` before we cross beyond `t` final character, since `t[7]` is `undefined` and outside `t` string so there is no hope for a true hence we return false;

Comment: I like that you pointed out that `j` is just the currentIndex of `t`. It gives me a good visual actually. Stepping back I can envision both `i` and `j` incrementing based on respective conditions. Thanks for the explanation.